# What if I pass a non existing resource pool in vertica?

Tags: database, vertica

What if I pass a non existing resource pool in vertica? 
Will it use the default resource pool then, if it doesn't finds that. I just need to confirm..

As in the log it shows this but it doesn't crashes and keeps running?

> `Could not find configured Resource Pool: my_resource_pool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will fall to the `general` resource pool.

In an running session, you can verify that by the command:
`SHOW resource_pool;`

After the fact , you can identify transaction_id and statement_id of the queries of that session in `query_requests`, and find the matching row(s) in `query_consumption`.